# Store Radiobutton int value (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button, sharedpreferences

> SCENARIO

There 3 radiobuttons inside a radiogroup, first radiobutton name is "A", second radiobutton name is "B" and third radiobutton is "C".

> QUESTION

1. How to get the int value that is if i select first radiobutton then it should get the int value of 2 and similarly if i select second and third radiobuttons then it should get the int value of 5 and 6.
2. Once i select any of the radiobutton then it automatically saves the int value in shared preference (For example i choose first radiobutton that value "2" get stored).
3. After i choose then i decided to close the app and open once again and see that first radiobutton is still selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the CheckedId of your RadioGroup and compare it with the Id from each RadioButton then set by the position of the values.

Example:

```
    int value;
    radioGroup.setOnCheckChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
            if (checkedId == R.id.buttonA) {
                value = 2;
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.buttonB) {
                value = 5;
            } else {
                value = 6;
            }
        }
```

Save that value on your preferences and when you get back to the app just check the position and do a radioGroup.check();

Comment: It worked, i can able to store the `int` value. But how to maintain that selected radiobutton means if i select first radiobutton and then close the app and open the app once again then that first radiobutton still selected ?

Comment: You can get the shared preferences that you stored and verify by the value with a switch case for example if you get 2 as value it is the first position radioGroup.check(R.id.buttonA).

Comment: I use this logic after destroying the app still it remain unchecked `if (value==2){
                        buttonA.setChecked(true);
                    }else {
                        buttonA.setChecked(false);
                    }`  Could you please help me in this.

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);       

int checked = preferences.getInt("yourKey", defaultValue);

if (checked == 2) {
    radioGroup.check(R.id.buttonA);
}

Comment: I use this logic but doesn't work `int method=sharedPreferences.getInt("key",4);
                    if (method==2){
                        radioOne.setChecked(true);
                    }else {
                        radioOne.setChecked(false);
                    }`

Comment: What value did you got on "method", did you used to store your preferences the shared prefs? Example: SharedPreferences.Edit edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
edit.putInt('key', value);
edit.apply();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222616/discussion-between-vinovite-and-sougat-riyadh).